# Getting the calling script path from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

In one of my bash scripts I use a variable that contains the path of the script. This variable is set like:

```
current_folder=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
```

As this script is a part of several ones, I want to move this code to a global imported script. But logically then the variable is filled with the path of the global script.

/MyProgram/common/globals.sh

```
current_folder=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
```

/MyProgram/modules/myscript.sh

```
. /MyProgram/common/globals.sh

echo "$current_folder" # Returns /MyProgram/common
```

Is there a way of doing this without creating a function and passing original path as a parameter?
Having to create code on every script in every request to use the path seems counter-productive.

Comment: You could change `BASH_SOURCE[0]` to `BASH_SOURCE[1]` to get the _caller_ of "globals.sh"

Comment: Why do you add the basename to $current_folder when you strip it off in the next line?

Comment: Just realized that @glenn-jackman. I came to fix it but you were faster. ;) Thanks.
But the BASH_SOURCE[1] is right. Why don't post it as the solution?

Comment: You could add an answer and accept it. That would benefit future readers of this question.

Answer (score 1):

As glenn jackman pointed, simply replacing the index in BASH_SOURCE to 1 solves the problem.

The GNU manual states the definition for BASH_SOURCE as:

> An array variable whose members are the source filenames where the
>   corresponding shell function names in the FUNCNAME array variable are
>   defined. The shell function ${FUNCNAME[$i]} is defined in the file
>   ${BASH_SOURCE[$i]} and called from ${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}

By it's definition getting the inmediate previous script in the call stack will be 1, so the code finally stays:

```
caller_path=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[1]}")" && pwd)
```